# Как подключить библиотеку OpenSSL на Windows для разработки на C++?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, криптография

В C++ обращаюсь к библиотеке OpenSSL для создания ключей x25519 и получения хэша sha512. На Debian с установленным OpenSSL код компилируется без проблем таким образом:

```
g++ main.cpp -lcrytpo -lssl
```

Установил на Windows 10 OpenSSL 1.1.1g из бинарного пакета (брал тут https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html **не** Light-версию). Итого после установки имею c:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\ с папками lib и include и прочим. Добавил %ProgramFiles%\OpenSSL-Win64\lib в переменное окружение LIB, %ProgramFiles%\OpenSSL-Win64\bin в PATH, но компиляция не удалась: поведение такое же, будто ничего не подключалось: undefined reference.
После этого добавлял в PATH все возможные и невозможные директории OpenSSL, но ничего не помогло. Пробовал явно указывать при компиляции и линковке путь с библиотеками:

```
g++ main.cpp "-L%ProgramFiles%\OpenSSL-Win64\lib" -lcrypto -lssl
```

Ничего результата не дало. Бьюсь не первые сутки. Прошу помощи: как же мне подключить OpenSSL на Windows?

Comment: Что значит "результата не дало"? Не находит библиотеку? Или как будто находит, но undefined references не пропадают?

Comment: В любом случае, как на счет перейти на MSYS2? В его пакетном менеджере есть OpenSSL, и его можно будет поставить без плясок с бубном. В качестве бонуса получите свежий гцц.

Comment: HolyBlackCat, при подключении библиотеки будто ничего не происходит, ошибка не меняется (undefined reference). При этом все указываемые пути перепроверял.

Comment: На MinGW такое обычно бывает, если разрядность библиотеки не совпадает с разрядностью компилятора. Совет остается тем же.

Answer (score 0):

Святые исходники!

Решение в моем случае: удалил MinGW, установил Strawberry по совету из мануала OpenSSL на GitHub. В переменном окружении PATH также убрал MinGW, оставив C:\Strawberry\c\bin. В этой директории находятся компиляторы и линковщики, есть тот же g++. Помимо этого "из коробки" имеются инклюды и библиотеки OpenSSL.

Завелось легко, как на Debian:

```
g++ main.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
```

Так много делал действий и столько ставил софта, что сейчас не могу уверенно сказать в чем была пробелема, но спасибо HolyBlackCat за наводку на разрядности компилятора и библиотеки.
Удачи в кодописании.